# Culture difference between Label and TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been playing with `WPF` for a while and I came across an interesting thing. When I bind `DateTime` object to the `Label`'s content then I see locally formatted representation of the date. However, when I bind to the `TextBlock`'s Text property then I actually see English one.

It seems that `TextBlock` is using some sort of converter whereas `Label` is just calling `ToString` method but I am not sure about it.

If so, why doesn't the `Label` use the converter too?

Is there any reason it works this way? I provide a short sample to let you guys inspect what's going on:

```
// MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="BindConversion.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding Dt}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Dt}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

// MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace BindConversion
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public DateTime Dt { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
            Dt = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a closer look to `Label` you will see that it derives from `ContentControl`.

`Content` property is displayed by a `ContentPresenter` where in the docs it is said the following:

*If there is a TypeConverter that converts the type of Content to a UIElement, the ContentPresenter uses that TypeConverter and the resulting UIElement is displayed.*

Now there is a `DateTimeConverter` inheriting from `TypeConverter`, the following snippet produces exactly the same string than a `Label` does:

```
var dateTimeConverter = new DateTimeConverter();
var convertToString = dateTimeConverter.ConvertToString(DateTime.Now);
```

**References:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.datetimeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ...and binding anything to a property of type String just calls `ToString()`

Comment: Right, and the TextBox is not deriving from ContentPresenter, thus not using a converter. That makes sense to me now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They are actually quite different beasts.

Check this out for more details:
https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/

Label actually isn't even a control

Comment: Yeah, I know that they are significantly different and that surely might be the reason why is it as it is. And you are wrong, TextBlock is not a control. But note that TextBox is a control and it behaves as TextBlock in given scenario.

Comment: You mean TextBlock is not a control, not label.